# Why is Power BI slicer case sensitive?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

In all doc, Power Query is case sensitive, and Power BI visuals/DAX are not. We have a slicer with the Search box turned on that is case sensitive. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table was DirectQuery to a Snowflake database. All columns in Snowflake default to case sensitive. This can be resolved by changing the COLLATE option on the column in Snowflake. 'ci' means case insensitive. See [Collation Support — Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html).

```
create or replace table table_name(
  ...
  column_name string collate 'ci',
  ...
);
```